# How can I return two header rows?

Tags: excel, vba

Below, I have part of a script that grabs the header row of a master file into an array before grabbing other data and printing it into a new worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CIB_Cuts()
    Dim j As Long, k As Long, x As Long
    Dim varArray() As Variant
    Dim varArray2() As Variant
    ReDim varArray(1 To 19, 1 To 1)

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
        ReDim varArray(1 To UBound(varArray, 1), 1 To 1)
        x = 1
        For k = 1 To UBound(varArray, 1)
            varArray(k, x) = .Cells(1, k)
        Next
```

What would I change to extract the first row for 19 columns and then then second row for 19 columns before it grabs the specific data I want elsewhere? 
I have two header rows and can extract only one.

Would I change the `ReDim varArray(1 To 19, 1 To 1)` to `ReDim varArray(1 To 19, 1 To 2` or would I have to edit the `with` statement below that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use static arrays and dynamic arrays appropriately. vDB is static array.

```
Dim j As Long, k As Long, x As Long
Dim varArray() As Variant
Dim varArray2() As Variant
Dim vDB As Variant

ReDim varArray(1 To 2, 1 To 19)

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
            vDB = .Range("a1").Resize(2, 19) '<~~vDB It is itself a two-line header.
            'if you want to pass data to a varArray array
            For k = 1 To UBound(varArray, 1)
                For x = 1 To UBound(varArray, 2)
                    varArray(k, x) = vDB(k, x)
                Next x
            Next

        End With
```

Working image.

[image]

Comment: it compiles the two rows into the array, but it presents a `subscript out of range` error on this line `varArray(k, x) = vDB(k, x)`

Comment: @nicklanta, In my test, it works well. I added a picture to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Paste Range Into Array

That's all you need (no looping).

```
Sub CIB_Cuts()
    Dim varArray As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
      varArray = .Range("A1:S2")
    End With
```

**This is a one-based two-dimensional 'horizontal' array i.e. it contains more columns than rows. So when you loop through it, it might look like this:**

```
For j = LBound(varArray, 2) to UBound(varArray, 2) ' more data
  For i = LBound(varArray) to UBound(varArray)
    x = varArray(i, j)
  Next  
Next
```

**instead of the classical 'vertical' array looping:**

```
For i = LBound(varArray) to UBound(varArray) ' more data
  For j = LBound(varArray, 2) to UBound(varArray, 2)
    x = varArray(i, j)
  Next
Next
```

**So if you want to loop through the data of first row (now in first column of array) you would do the following:**

```
For i = LBound(varArray) to UBound(varArray) ' more data
  x = varArray(1, i)
Next
```

**or for the second row (now in second column of array) you would do this:**

```
For i = LBound(varArray) to UBound(varArray) ' more data
  x = varArray(2, i)
Next
```

**The complete code could look like this:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CIBCutsPaste()
    Dim varArray As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
      varArray = .Range("A1:S2")
    End With

    ' Print contents to Immediate Window
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
      Dim str1 As String
      Dim k As Integer
      Dim x As Integer
      For k = 1 To UBound(varArray)         ' 2 Rows
        For x = 1 To UBound(varArray, 2)    ' 19 Columns
          If x = 1 Then
            str1 = str1 & vbCr & varArray(k, x)
           Else
            str1 = str1 & "," & varArray(k, x)
          End If
        Next
      Next
      Debug.Print str1
    End With

End Sub
```

**If you insist on looping i.e. copying rows of worksheet into columns of array, it could look like this:**

```
Sub CIBCutsLoop()
    k As Long, x As Long
    Dim varArray() As Variant
    ReDim varArray(1 To 19, 1 To 2)

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
        For k = 1 To UBound(varArray)         ' 19 Rows
            For x = 1 To UBound(varArray, 2)  ' 2 Columns
                varArray(k, x) = .Cells(x, k)
            Next
        Next
    End With

    ' Print contents to Immediate Window
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
        Dim str1 As String
        For k = 1 To UBound(varArray)         ' 19 Rows
            For x = 1 To UBound(varArray, 2)  ' 2 Columns
                If x = 1 Then
                    str1 = str1 & vbCr & varArray(k, x)
                  Else
                    str1 = str1 & "," & varArray(k, x)
                End If
            Next
        Next
        Debug.Print str1
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You beat me to it. :) In addition, I'd recommend something like [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) as a lecture for OP.